# i want to build audioserver (/frameworks/av/media/audioserver) to 64-bit in android ,and it can't startup

Tags: android, c++, c, android.mk

I want to build audioserver(/frameworks/av/media/audioserver) to 64-bit, and refer to the instructions in Android.mk (/frameworks/av/media/audioserver/Android.mk), add AUDIOSERVER_MULTILIB :=64 in device.mk,but it can't start, check the log and find the following error.
01-20 09:44:31.637  2581  2581 F linker  : CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/audioserver": 
unsupported ELF TLS DT entry in "/system/lib64/libaudioflinger.so"

console:/system/bin # file audioserver
audioserver: ELF shared object, 64-bit LSB arm64, dynamic (/system/bin/linker64), for Android 28, BuildID=01599, stripped

console:/system/lib64 # file libaudioflinger.so
libaudioflinger.so: ELF shared object, 64-bit LSB arm64, for Android 28, BuildID=fd41f, stripped

/frameworks/av/media/audioserver/Android.mk

```
# If AUDIOSERVER_MULTILIB in device.mk is non-empty then it is used to control
# the LOCAL_MULTILIB for all audioserver exclusive libraries.
# This is relevant for 64 bit architectures where either or both
# 32 and 64 bit libraries may be built.
#
# AUDIOSERVER_MULTILIB may be set as follows:
#   32      to build 32 bit audioserver libraries and 32 bit audioserver.
#   64      to build 64 bit audioserver libraries and 64 bit audioserver.
#   both    to build both 32 bit and 64 bit libraries,
#           and use primary target architecture (32 or 64) for audioserver.
#   first   to build libraries and audioserver for the primary target architecture only.
#   <empty> to build both 32 and 64 bit libraries and 32 bit audioserver.
```

audioserver should work normally

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered on the google mailing list "android-porting". I'm just quoting the answer.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-porting/lK7dDeJT0k4

> "As of now, the AOSP release of Android does not yet officially support 64-bit audioserver.
>   We are considering adding 64-bit option for audioserver in a future release,
>   but I can't give you a schedule of when that might happen.
>   Even then, it may be limited to platforms that are capable of supporting it
>   (for example due to dependencies on various libraries etc.)."
>   (Glenn Kasten, Jan 25th 2019)